# Express a ternary SQL data type

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes, ternary

## Context

I just met a single table in a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database which is actually only defining a **triplet** of coded values that are used across the whole database as a ternary data type. I am a bit astonished at first glance, I feel it's weird; there should be some **ternary data type**?
I've searched the web, especially the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/) without any apparent success (I'm probably wrong with my search keywords?!), but maybe there is no other solution.

## Question

I would like to know if it exists a ternary (as comparison with binary or boolean) data type in PostgreSQL or more generally in SQL which permits to express a "ternary state" (or "ternary boolean" which is clearly is an abuse of language), which I would represent as a general idea as:

```
+-------+----------+--------------------+
| id    |     type |  also expressed as |
+-------+----------+--------------------+
| 0     |    false |                  0 |
| 1     |     true |                  1 |
| 2     |  unknown |                  2 |
+-------+----------+--------------------+
```

where `unknown` can be whatever third state you are actually dealing with.

Comment: This is unclear.  An operator usually works on two or more operands.  "true" and "false" are boolean constants.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know if it exists a ternary (as comparison with binary or boolean) data type

Actually, the `boolean` data type **is** ternary because it can have the values `true`, `false` and `null`.

Consider this table:

```
create table data (some_number int, some_flag boolean);
```

And the following data:

```
insert into data (some_number, some_flag)
values (1, true), (2, false), (3, null);
```

Then the following:

```
select *
from data
where some_flag = false;
```

will only return one row (with some_number = 2)

Answer (score 1):

```
there is not a  specific ternary operator but you could use case  


   select case when operator =0 then 'false'
                when operatore =1 then 'true'
                when operator = 2 then 'unknow'
                else 'not managed'
              end 
  from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

I second a_horse_with_no_name's solution for your specific example, but the more general approach is to use an enum data type:

```
CREATE TYPE ternary AS ENUM (
   'never',
   'sometimes',
   'always'
);
```

Constants of such a data type are written as string constantls, e.g. `'never'`, but the internal storage uses 4 bytes per value, regardless of the length of the label.